# Using _inpd _outpd under VS2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I need to migrate an old library compiled with VS2005 to VS2015.

This library uses commands: **_inpd** and **_outpd** and seems to be no longer supported by Microsoft, as I can see from this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7ae61bc.aspx .

Is there a workaround to this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could take a look at the implementation in a previous VS runtime and copy that. Unfortunately I don't really understand what the functions do (writing to COM port? or some other ports?), so I cannot suggest other winapi functions.

Comment: We use it for read and write a byte in a PCI device.

Comment: Copying vc/crt/src/intel/inp.asm and outp.asm from a previous version of VS is the way to get ahead.  Very small, you can also do it with inline assembly with the __asm keyword.  Using LoadLibrary + GetProcAddress on msvcrt.dll is another way.

Comment: I'll do and let you know. Feel free to post it as answer.